# Do background images load faster than embedded images in HTML and how are they read by screen readers?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Do background images and embedded images take about the same time to load on a HTML page provided they are the same size? If I am to use the same image twice in a page - once as a background and once as a normal embedded image, which loads faster?

For making a website compatible with screen readers, what's the best way to include an image? Are background images read well by screen readers or do they simply ignore the background images?

Comment: Different browsers may have different optimizations, but I imagine the bottleneck in both cases would be in downloading the image, not in how/where it's rendered in the output.  So it would essentially be the same.  For the screen reader, how would you expect it to read the image?  If the image is part of the styling, the screen reader will probably (and rightly should) ignore it.  If it's part of the markup, then I imagine the screen reader may be configured to indicate that an image is present and maybe some information about the image (such as its `alt` tag).

Comment: The big win with background images is spriting (fewer HTTP requests). As for accessibility, image replacement techniques can handle that.

Answer (score 3):

> Do background images and embedded images take about the same time to load on a HTML page provided they are the same size?

I would say yes, but I think it also depends on how they are loaded. There used to be a practise called image pre-loading. I never did speed tests personally to know if it was really benefitical.

> For making a website compatible with screen readers, what's the best way to include an image? Are background images read well by screen readers or do they simply ignore the background images?

Screen readers do not announce that `<body>`, `<div>`, etc has a background image attached. There is no magical place for an `alt` attribute in this case. You need to keep in mind that you're keeping good contrast between your image and your text color. WebAIM has a great [color contrast checker](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/), in my opinion.

If you are using CSS to position text over an image that's used as background, so you can give it an `alt`, don't. That image probably should have a null alt (`<img src="..." alt=""/>`) anyhow.

Comment: `<img src="..." alt=""/>`
I get your point but this may not be ideal for SEO? I guess in some situations like this, we can't make it ideal for both SEO and accessibility. We have to prioritise one over the other. If the image is there to act as a background, it'd be better to use it as a background through CSS rather than directly embedding it in a code.

Comment: Keyword stuffing is a bad way to do SEO. Bloating alt's for background images would do more harm thann good. Natural SEO includes writing content so variations of your keyword(s) appear naturally, think it is 1-3 times every 200 words. Using heading tags smartly, again using keywords naturally. Using the keyword and description `meta` tags. I have never heard of a good source sying null alts ding you for SEO. AFAIK good code outweighs keyword stuffed garbage.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an image both as background AND as image (i.e. Using the same image twice) you technically only need to load that image once, assuming your images are properly cached...
That is once you loaded an image with a cache header, or that image is downloading, the browser will either load it from the cache or wait for that one image to finish loading.

As to whether background images and embedded images take about the same time to load. Let's get some context. As per google: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/browser-paint-events

> Finally, notice that each image itself renders progressively, so that
>   the the user begins to see the image content before the entire image
>   has finished loading. Modern browsers render images in HTML  tags
>   progressively. By contrast, many browsers do not render images
>   specified using CSS background-image attributes progressively. To
>   enable progressive rendering of images, use an HTML  tag instead
>   of a CSS background-image attribute.

So an image using the <img> tag will load faster and not hold up the DOM from being ready unlike an inline css background-image in older browsers which could slow things down.

However, the caveats with progressive rendering of an <img> are that, if your image is not fully loaded when the widow.onload event fires (which is almost always true for large images), it makes for a rather ugly progressive rendering, as well as causing a paint reflow when the image is set as responsive using auto-width and/or 100% width.

To make inline images load much faster and in a much nicer way, what I did is:

First, preload them extremely early as css backgrounds  in AND on the <head> of the page. You can start preloading some or all of your css images too that way, before your css file or body have been parsed.

Second, to go around the other drawbacks, I use a javascript lazy-load-ish method to hide the image on the interactive event before the window loads.

And finally, bring the image as a fade-in once the css-called image has finished loading.

You can see a live example at: http://www.nptr.net/1614

So while an embedded image is best. If you care about the best speed for your page load, I highly recommend to preload large images early via css background(s) in the head, especially if you must use them as backgrounds right away.

That is because otherwise, images in your body will have to wait until both your css file(s) and synchronous javascript(s) are fully received, until the browser actually starts retrieving them. Which generally incurs a 100 to 500ms delay, with the worst delay being on the first page load.